# Angularjs(1.3.6+) $resource interceptors and global 401 handlers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-401, angular-http-interceptors

My question is about `$resource`'s interceptor(responseError). I want to emphasize that the angularjs I based on is `V1.3.6`.

Problem:

```
app.factory('authInterceptor',['$q', '$location', '$log', function($q, $location, $log){
    $log.debug('this is a regular factory with injection');
    return {
        responseError: function(response){
            console.log(response)
            // problem is that I cant check 401 by response.status, 
            // because the response here is AN ERROR OBJECT like `SyntaxError: ...`. Anyway to get the status?
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
}])
```

When I get 401 response, `responseError`'s arguments is AN ERROR OBJECT like `SyntaxError: Unexpected token U` because the reponse from server is plain text `Unathorized` with status `401`.

But I want to get the `response.status`, and do something if it is `401`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This question should be closed because I finally found answer myself.

When response is 401/404 and anything besides 200, `transformResponse` still executed and an **error** occurred! This **error** just cover the normal response(has status property), so I never get the original response inside interceptor!

I think it's stupid to execute `transformResponse` if the response's status is not 200! And inside `transformResponse`, you can't access status code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple interceptor that handles 401s, as well does some configuration:

```
angular.module('notesApp', [])
  .factory('AuthInterceptor',['AuthInfoService', '$q', function(AuthInfoService, $q) {
      return {

        responseError: function(responseError) {
              if (responseError.status === 401) { // authentication issue
                    //redirect user to login or do something else...
              }
              return $q.reject(responseError);
        }
     };
 }])
 .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
}]);
```

** Here is an interceptor that only intercepts incoming responses with a non-200 status code.** 
If the status code is 401, the user is redirected to the login page. In this case, the promise is rejected so that the controller or service still sees a failure

Comment: So, where is `responseError.status` from? The responseError is undefined. And what's `AuthInfoService`?

Comment: I edited the successHandler to make things a bit clearer. responseError is the argument in the successHandler of the promise. AuthInfoService is a service that helps get the authorization header is the request. It also can redirect the user to loginpage. But you don't need it.

Comment: Please check my question again. My problem is that `response.status` is  undefined! and that is your `responseError.status` is undefined. Angular1.3.6

Comment: Are you using grunt build?Check which CDN it is loading. You may also look into Angular V1.3.8 or something else There should not be an issue. Check out this JonasHartmann code: http://plnkr.co/edit/s3ld5b?p=preview

Comment: When response is 401/404 and anything besides 200, `transformResponse` still executed and an error occurred! This error just cover the normal response(has status property), so I never get the original response inside interceptor!